# Can I control which device a parent controls request is sent to?

Tags: parental-controls

My son has an iPhone, I don't. I use a Mac and an iPad. We have parental controls set such that any new app he wants to install on his iPhone requires me to approve it.

When he requests permission to install a new app, the notification will come up on one of my devices, but not all of them, and not always the same one.

It seems ridiculous to have to check my iPad and two iMacs (one of which is in my office at work!) in order to approve a request. Is there any way to specify which device I want these requests to be sent to?

Comment: Are all your devices online all the time? I am assuming you are signed-in with the same Apple ID on all three of them (2 iMacs + iPad).

Comment: Yes, I'm generally logged into all three devices with the same Apple ID, and I don't bother to log out when I leave (I have screensaver set to require password)